# How could I randomize the color attribute for an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid of listed elements and my purpose is to randomize their loading background color. Until now all elements have the same background (`thumbnailBackgroundColor`) and this is set like this in the HTML file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/FWDIGP.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">    

    FWDRLUtils.onReady(function(){    
        new FWDIGP({        
            thumbnailBackgroundColor:"#111111"     
            });
        });
</script>
```

The grid inside the body is coded like this:

```
<ul>
<li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg" data-thumbnail-overlay-color="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
</ul>
```

and this is the function on JavaScript

```
this.setupPoolThumbs = function() {
        for (var o = 0; o < this.maxThumbs; o++) {
            FWDIGPThumb.setPrototype();
            e = new FWDIGPThumb(this, this.thumbnailTransitionType_str, this.thumbnailBackgroundColor_str, this.thumbnailOverlayBackgroundColor_str, n.thumbnailOverlayOpacity, n.showThumbnailOverlay_bl, this.isMobile_bl, n.showThumbnailIcon_bl, i.disableThumbnailInteractivity_bl);
            e.setVisible(false);
            e.addListener(FWDIGPThumb.MOUSE_OVER, this.onMouseOverHandler);
            e.addListener(FWDIGPThumb.MOUSE_UP, this.onMouseUpHandler);                
        }
    };
```

How could I randomize the `thumbnailBackgroundColor` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is able to convert an integer into a base-16 (hex) string using the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function. You can use this particular function to generate a random number, and then in turn convert it a valid hex colour string.

Here's the basis code (courtesy of [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/)):

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

You can place this inline within the constructor, so your code will look as follows:

```
FWDRLUtils.onReady(function(){    
    new FWDIGP({        
        thumbnailBackgroundColor: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
    });
});
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. Is there a similar solution for use it inside the `<li>` for the `data-thumbnail-overlay-color=""` attribute?

Comment: I suppose. You could just set the data attribute's value to the return of a function.